# ubuntu 11.04 java 6 sun fonts

Tags: java, ubuntu, fonts, phpstorm

I've just installed ubuntu and JVM phpstorm but gui fonts looks very ugly.
It is Java based php IDE I used to.
Is any solutions to fix the interface?

Comment: Is the IDE netbeans by any chance?

Comment: Check my reply in this URL:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360707/java-fonts-look-garbled-on-linux-but-fine-on-windows/9509919#9509919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is JetBrains product you should be able to change font through File > Settings > IDE Settings > Appearance and change default fonts there